# Upload multile image as a queue with showing progress bar like whats app

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, android-progressbar

I have an image-uploading activity which is working fine. It is uploading the image. I want the "upload activity" to be done in the background. It should be  started automatically if there is any pending image to be upload as network reconnects. I also want to show image wise progress bar like whats app with retry option.

I am using httpurlconnection class for uploading .jpg image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used Intent service for this

in my activity class I called When Upload button is clicked

```
public void uploadImage(View v)
{
    // When Image is selected from Gallery
    if (ImgPath != null && !ImgPath.isEmpty()) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Uploading started",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    triggerImageUpload();
    } 
    else 
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "You must select image from gallery before you try to upload",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public void triggerImageUpload() 
{    
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyIntentService.class);
   intent.putExtra("filename", fileName);
   intent.putExtra("imageid", IMAGE_ID);
   intent.putExtra("imgPath", ImgPath);
   this.startService(intent);
}
```

and code for MyIntentService.class

```
public class MyIntentService extends IntentService
{
   int IMAGE_ID;     
   NotificationManager notificationManager;
   Notification myNotification;

  //private Builder builder;     
  public static final String ACTION_MyIntentService = "com.example.androidintentservice.RESPONSE";
  public static final String ACTION_MyUpdate = "com.example.androidintentservice.UPDATE";    
  public static final String EXTRA_KEY_OUT = "EXTRA_OUT";
  public static final String EXTRA_KEY_UPDATE = "EXTRA_UPDATE";

String extraOut;     
//boolean status;
String title;
String contentText;

// Defines and instantiates an object for handling status updates.
//private BroadcastNotifier mBroadcaster;    
//RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
String filename,imgPath,ticNo;
private int serverResponseCode;


public MyIntentService() 
{
    super("MyIntentService");
}

@Override
public void onCreate() 
{
    super.onCreate();
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);     
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) 
{
    //get input
    ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
    Boolean isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
    if(isInternetPresent)
    {
        filename=intent.getExtras().getString("filename");
        imgPath=intent.getExtras().getString("imgPath");
        IMAGE_ID=intent.getExtras().getInt("imageid");
       // ticNo=intent.getExtras().getString("ticNo");
        extraOut = filename;

        contentText="Uploading...";
        title=filename+" Uploading..";
        generateNotification(title, contentText);

        try 
        {
            uploadFile(imgPath,filename);
        }
        catch (Exception exception) 
        {
            title=filename+"";
            generateNotification(title, "Upload Failed..Something went wrong at server end");
        }      
    }
    else
    {
        title=filename+"";
        generateNotification(title, "Upload Failed..No Internet Connection");
    }
}

public void uploadFile(String sourceFileUri,String fileName) 
{
    try
    {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy= new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        //fileName = sourceFileUri;
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;  
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
        File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 

        if (!sourceFile.isFile()) 
        {
            title=fileName+"";
            generateNotification(title, "Upload Failed..File Not Found");
            //General.listItem.remove(filename);
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                String upLoadServerUri = "http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/phpwebservice/upload_media.php";
                URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
                // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 

                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""+ fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                // create a buffer of  maximum size
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // read file and write it into form...
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  


                while (bytesRead > 0) 
                {
                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }

                // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                // Responses from the server (code and message)
                serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                if(serverResponseCode == 200)
                {
                    addToDb();
                }
                else
                {
                    title=filename+"";
                    generateNotification(title, "Uploading Failed..Server Not Responding");
                    }

                //close the streams //
                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                title=filename+"";
                generateNotification(title, "Uploading Failed..Server Not Responding.");

            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception etx) 
    {
        title=filename+"";
        generateNotification(title, "Uploading Failed..No Internet Connection.");
    }
}

public void generateNotification(String title,String contentText){
     myNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
       .setContentTitle(title)
       .setContentText(contentText)
       .setTicker("Notification!")
       .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())        
       .setAutoCancel(true)
       .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.upload1)
       .build();

       notificationManager.notify(IMAGE_ID, myNotification);        
}

public void sendBroadcastToActivity(String action,String message){
      Intent intentResponse = new Intent();
      intentResponse.setAction(action);
      intentResponse.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
      if(action.equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_MyUpdate)){
          int progress=Integer.parseInt(message);
          intentResponse.putExtra(EXTRA_KEY_UPDATE,progress);
      }else{
          intentResponse.putExtra(EXTRA_KEY_OUT, message);
      }
      sendBroadcast(intentResponse);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use Multi-part file upload to ensure that the uploading resumes if the connection is lost. here's the [code](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/5CMO0iwZZ3I) to achieve this in background. you have to use progress dialog to show progress and upload percentage. Here the [link](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi) to required jar.

Comment: thank for quick reply but link you have provided is removed please send me the exact link

Comment: i have added the links